# VBA Pivot Table error "Invalid procedure call or argument"

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Please help me debug this code.
I am getting the following error:

> "Invalid procedure call or argument"

Code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "MainSheet!R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C9", Version:=xPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot Sheet!R2C1", TableName:="Compile table", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Comment: Try splitting it out into two lines (create the cache, and then the pivot table).  For some reason that sometimes fixes things.

Comment: HI , i split the code as u said by still getting the error

Comment: Set pca = wb1.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="MainSheet!R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C9", Version:=xPivotTableVersion15)
    Set pca = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="Pivot Sheet!A1", TableName:="Compiletable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Comment: Set pca = wb1.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="MainSheet!R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C9", Version:=xPivotTableVersion15)
    Set pca = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="Pivot Sheet!A1", TableName:="Compiletable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Comment: `xPivotTableVersion15`  ?  Is that typo in your original code?

Comment: Does the sheet exist that you try to place the pivot table on?

Comment: thanks ,that made the first line run     Set pca = wb1.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="MainSheet!R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C9", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15) now the secound line is giving the same error  Set pca1 = pca.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="Pivot Sheet!A1", TableName:="Compiletable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Comment: thanks ,that made the first line run     Set pca = wb1.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="MainSheet!R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C9", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15) now the secound line is giving the same error  Set pca1 = pca.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="Pivot Sheet!A1", TableName:="Compiletable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Comment: ya "Pivot Sheet" sheet exists

Answer (score 0):

`xPivotTableVersion15` looks like a typo and

```
TableDestination:="'Pivot Sheet'!A1"
```

sheet names with spaces need to be enclosed in single quotes

Answer (score 0):

I did a macro in Excel 2016 and a user on an older version of Excel got this error. In my code it had Version:=6 and DefaultVersion:=6. When I changed this to be xlPivotTableVersion14 it worked fine.